# change a colored image represented as a numpy ndarray to greyscale

Tags: python, numpy

I have an image, loaded from a file thus:

```
img = misc.imread('mypic.jpg')
```

it is a 3 dimensional, RGB numpy.ndarray.
I wish to turn it into a greyscale ndarray (1-D).

Comment: Have you anything particular in mind? Anything you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question, but I think this should do what you want:

```
img = misc.imread('mypic.jpg', flatten=True)
```

See the documentation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html

Comment: That's exactly what I asked. Is there a way to do this on the NxMx3 RGB array? without reading the file from disk again?

Comment: In that case I would go for the solution provided in the link by @Ophion.